# What is the inverse image sheaf necessary for in algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

Given a continuous map $f \colon X \to Y$ of topological spaces, and a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$, the inverse image sheaf $f^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is the sheafification of the presheaf
$$U \mapsto \varinjlim_{V \supseteq f(U)} \Gamma(V, \mathcal{F}).$$
If $X$ and $Y$ happen to be ringed spaces, $f$ a morphism of ringed spaces, and $\mathcal{F}$ an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, one then defines the pullback sheaf $f^* \mathcal{F}$ on $X$ as
$$f^{-1}\mathcal{F} \otimes_{f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_Y} \mathcal{O}_X.$$
However, I cannot think of any other usage of the inverse image sheaf in algebraic geometry.  Moreover, if $X$ and $Y$ are schemes and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent, there is an alternate way of defining $f^* \mathcal{F}$. Given $f \colon \mathrm{Spec} B \to \mathrm{Spec} A$, and $\mathcal{F} = \widetilde{M}$, where $M$ is an $A$-module, one defines $f^* \mathcal{F}$ to be the sheaf associated to the $B$-module $M \otimes_A B$.  To extend this to arbitrary schemes, it is necessary to prove that it is well-defined; but I still think it is easier to work with than the other definition, which involves direct limits and two sheafifications of presheaves (the inverse image, and the tensor product).  I have not checked, but I imagine that something similar can be done for formal schemes.

Hence, my question:

> What uses, if any, does the inverse image sheaf have in algebraic geometry, other than to define the pullback sheaf?

A closely related question is

> In a course on schemes, is there a good reason to define the inverse image sheaf and the pullback sheaf for ringed spaces in general, rather than simply defining the pullback of a quasicoherent sheaf by a morphism of schemes?

To go from the first question to the second question, I suppose one must also address whether there are $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules significant to algebraic geometers that are not quasicoherent.

**Edit:** I think the question deserves a certain amount of clarification.  Several people have given interesting descriptions or explications of the inverse image sheaf.  While I appreciate these, they are not the point of my question; I am, specifically, interested to know whether there are constructions or arguments in algebraic geometry that cannot reasonably be done without using the inverse image sheaf. So far, the answer seems to be that such things exist, but are not really within the scope of, say, a one-year first course on schemes. There are other constructions (such as the inverse image ideal sheaf) that do not, strictly speaking, require the inverse image sheaf, but for which it may be more appropriate to use the inverse image sheaf as a matter of taste.

Comment: Motivation: I'm giving a lecture in a student seminar based on Ravi Vakil's notes, and I'd like a good excuse not to cover the inverse image sheaf.  I figure that if I ask this question, either I'll get such an excuse or (probably more likely) I'll learn something.

Comment: This exact question came up in the Wisconsin reading group for Ravi's notes!

Comment: The other place I'm aware of where it appear in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry book is in the discussion of blow-ups.  See page 163.  This definition can be describe by $f^*$ though too as Hartshorne points out in 7.12.2.

Comment: Actually, another place where this occasionally is used is the following. Say a finite map of varieties $f : Y \to X$.  It is convenient sometimes to just work on only one topological space, and in particular the topological space of $Y$.  In that case, working with the ringed space $(Y, f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_X)$ is basically like working on $X$ (and if you have  sheaves on $X$, you can apply $f^{-1}$ and work on $Y$).  Dually, use $f_*$ and work on $X$.  This is done for various dualities for finite maps, but it is generally a notation which is swept under the rug (as it should be).

Comment: I really like the way it's covered in the stacks project.  Hartshorne's definition crams the sheafification and the inverse image presheaf into one functor.  It becomes much clearer when viewed as a composition.

Comment: Charles, how do you propose to define pullback maps in sheaf cohomology for a map between general (perhaps non-noetherian and non-separated) schemes, since one can't expect to get by using quasi-coherent injective sheaves of modules?  There is something nice about having one concept of ringed space cohomological pullback which unifies all others (e.g., in deRham theory, topology, etc.).

Comment: What about the definition of Y-linear differential operators on a Y-scheme X/Y (as in EGA 4 Ch. 16, for example)? Or, for that matter, what about the cotangent complex of X/Y? Alternatively, if one is thinking about sheaves of sets on Y that are not O_Y-modules, then, of course, there is nothing but the inverse image. One might consider sheaves of sets that are not O_X-modules when formulating moduli problems or, to change the context a bit, when working with etale cohomology.

Comment: The inverse image presheaf functor is very easy to describe.  It's given as a left Kan extension $\operatorname{Lan}_{u^{-1^{op}}}:\operatorname{Set}^{O(Y)^{op}}\to \operatorname{Set}^{O(X)^{op}}$ of $u^{-1^{op}}:O(Y)^{op}\to O(X)^{op}$.  We can also see that the sheafification is left adjoint to the inclusion $Sh\hookrightarrow Psh$, and everything becomes clear.  That is, it's just a matter of checking things for presheaves (namely that precomposition with $u^{-1}$ commutes with limits), then applying the general formula for pointwise left Kan extensions (and sheafification).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By some coincidence, I have a student going through this stuff now, and we got to this point this just yesterday.

The definition of $f^{-1}$ is certainly disconcerting at first, but it's not that bad.
You'd like to say
$$f^{-1}\mathcal{F}(U) = \mathcal{F}(f(U))$$
except it doesn't make sense as it stands, unless $f(U)$ is open. So we approximate
by open sets from above. A section on the left is a germ of a section of $\mathcal{F}$ defined in some
open neighbourhood of $f(U)$, where by germ I mean the equivalence class where you identify two sections if
they agree on a smaller neigbourhood.
Even if you're still unhappy with this, the adjointness property tells you that it
is the right thing to look at.

Also, some of us work with non-quasicoherent sheaves (e.g. locally constant sheaves or constructible sheaves), so it's nice to have a general construction.

**Addendum:** In my answer yesterday, I had somehow forgotten to mention
the etale space or sheaf as a bunch of stalks 
$$\coprod_y \mathcal{F}_y\to Y$$
viewpoint 
discussed by Emerton and  Martin Brandenburg.  Had you started with this "bundle picture",
we would be having this discussion in reverse, because pullback is the natural operation here and pushforward is the thing that seems strange.

Comment: Bingo -- there are so many sheaves of interest apart from quasi-coherent sheaves (e.g., etale topology, or just injective sheaves on modules on a general scheme!), and even when proving things about ringed-space pullback it cleans things up to separate the issues in topological pullback from the issues in the tensoring step. Plus, later in life one meets complex-analytic spaces, rigid-analytic spaces, formal schemes, etc., and so developing good habits early on makes later adjustments straightforward (as opposed to having to "unlearn" bad definitions and redo all the basic proofs). 

Comment: The characterization you've given for the inverse image presheaf is not that bad. But it becomes worse when you sheafify. Not unworkable, but worse. One of the nice things about working in affine sets is that you don't have to sheafify.

Comment: Charles, why the objection to sheafifying? It's an absolutely basic fact of life with sheaves (e.g., quotients). There are plenty of non-scheme geometric theories (e.g., manifolds) where one forms tensor products of sheaves (e.g., with vector bundles) and uses quotients, etc. for which there is no crutch of affines and one has to sheafify to get the big picture.  Moreover, the sheaf-theoretic unification of topology and function theory in complex variables is marvelous, and there's no crutch of affine opens or quasi-coherence there either. Over-reliance on quasi-coherence misses too much. 

Comment: Sheafification is probably best thought of as the left adjoint to the inclusion $Sh\hookrightarrow Psh$.  You can derive pretty much all of its properties from that fact.  The hands-on construction is really just a proof of existence.

Comment: Harry, it is important to be able to "compute" things in both proofs and examples. For example, how do you prove using abstract adjoint nonsense stuff that sheafification preserves monicity (which involves maps in the "wrong" direction relative to the adjunction property)? For this and other reasons, I think it is a mistake to disregard the hands-on construction too much. 

Comment: @BCnrd: Yes, I weaken my statement accordingly, although if I remember correctly, you can prove that it preserves monicity with more abstract nonsense (the inclusion is right-exact?).

Comment: Dear Harry: for a monic map $F \rightarrow G$ of presheaves let's try to use abstract gibberish to deduce that the induced map $F^+ \rightarrow G^+$ of sheafifications is monic. Well, it means that  ${\rm{Hom}}(H,F^+) \rightarrow {\rm{Hom}}(H,G^+)$ is injective for any sheaf $H$.  But the sheafifications are on the "wrong" side in the Hom's to apply adjointness, so no dice for this as best I can tell. If you know an argument, please do tell the idea. 

Comment: BCnrd: I think "objection" might be too strong a word, but my difficulty with sheafifying is that it adds an extra complication to be considered when trying to state explicitly what a section over an open set is. While I know there are times when this cannot be avoided, I like to avoid it where possible.

Comment: @Charles: The important thing to note here is that it is extremely easy to compute in Psh.  Indeed, since sheafification is a left adjoint and lex (and therefore exact), we can compute lots of categorical constructions naively in Psh (where everything is just computed pointwise), then pass to the sheafification to get the correct result.  

Comment: Dear Charles:  you're right that computing sheafification is often impossible over "general" open sets, and so when we can nail it down on specific opens that is good for proofs, calculations, etc.  But theoretically it is important to not develop a theory which suppresses it (e.g., when teaching/learning about sheaves, getting a grip on sheafification is an essential part of the process, both where it's easy to compute on the nose and, when not, how to deal with it). For example, good exercise that $\Omega^4_M$ is sheafification of presheaf 4th wedge power of $\Omega^1_M$ for manifolds $M$.

Comment: Dear Charles, The difficulty of computing sections of presheaves over general open sets is one reason for emphasizing the "stalk" point of view that I discuss in my answer.  This is a very natural, and very topological, point of view (which it took me some time to appreciate as a student, since it not emphasized that much).   It is very close to the often maligned espace etale point of view of sheaves; note that
this point of view makes inverse images trivial, since they are literally given by taking a fibre product of the espace etale.  As Brian emphasizes, when you choose what to ...

Comment: ... teach, and what to omit, it is not just a question of how quickly you get to some desired destination, but what techniques and habits of thought are taught along the way.  (Indeed, the latter is really more important than the former, in my view.)  I think I'm speaking for Brian as well as myself in saying that the techniques and the intuitions that you pick up in learning to deal with sheafification and inverse image are important and useful, and will well repay the time and effort taken to learn them.

Comment: @BCnrd: Meanwhile, with respect to your earlier question about an abstract-nonsense way to prove that sheafification is lex: Use the localization characterization of descent (localizing at "local isomorphisms", which are local epis with a locally epi relative diagonal).  It's easy to show that $Sh$ is equivalent to the localization, and that sheafification is the localization functor.  The lex property follows from the closure properties of local isos with respect to the pullback.

Comment: This does not depend on any prior construction of the sheafification.  Everything follows from the axioms (although showing that the Grothendieck topology and local isomorphism approaches to descent are equivalent is not immediate).  

Comment: Dear Harry: I have no idea what your argument is saying. What does "localization characterization of descent" mean? Please convey in simpler terms how you are bypassing that the naive approach to an adjointness argument hits the snag of monicity being defined in terms of maps to a sheafication, in contrast with the latter's characterization by maps out of it. Are you claiming to characterize a left adjoint to sheafification? Can you strip away the words a bit and tell me a concrete idea that I am missing? Let's stick with ordinary top. spaces, so surely Groth. topologies cannot be necessary.

Comment: General fact: If $C$ is locally presentable and $W$ is a class of weak equivalences containing all identities, closed under 2-out-of-3 and satisfying the following requirement: $X\to Y\in W$ iff for any morphism $Z\to Y\in Arr(C)$, $X\times_Y Z\to Z\in W$.  Then the localization map $\gamma: C\to C[W^{-1}]$ is lex.  When $C=Psh$, such classes $W$ are characterized exactly as the classes of morphisms mapping to isomorphisms under sheafification for some topology $\tau$. 

Comment: So let's look at the concrete case for a moment.  The canonical topology on $\tau$ on $X$ gives rise to an inclusion functor $Sh_\tau\hookrightarrow Psh$, and we can see that this inclusion admits a left adjoint $r_\tau$, called sheafification.  Let $W_\tau$ be the class  of morphisms $f\in Arr(Psh)$ such that $r(f)$ is an isomorphism in $Sh_\tau$.  It turns out (with a bit of work) that $\gamma:Psh\to Psh[W_\tau^{-1}]\simeq Sh_\tau$ is isomorphic to $r_\tau$.  That is, we can identify $r_\tau$ with a localization map.

Comment: It follows by the characterization of "maps that are isomorphisms under sheafification" in SGA 4.1.i and 4.1.ii that our class $W_\tau$ satisfies the properties required on $W$ (from two comments ago) for $\gamma$ to be lex (we will call any such class of morphisms in $Psh$ a "system of local isomorphisms) .  That is, the left-exactness of $r_\tau$ follows from the fact that it is naturally isomorphic to $\gamma$.  

Comment: It then suffices to give a proof of the "general fact" cited above.  I don't have the time to write up a proof right now, and I can't think of a reference offhand, but I'm sure that you shouldn't have any trouble proving it yourself if you care enough to bother with it.

Comment: Harry, I agree that category of sheaves is a localization of that of presheaves for the evident class of morphisms (and via the sheafification functor), so your point is that there is an abstract criterion for left-exactness of localization of categories. I didn't know that. To verify that criterion you seem to use that if a map of presheaves induces an isom. on sheafifications then same is true after any pullback. That in turn seems to use that sheafification commutes with fiber product...but isn't that a disguised version of the left-exactness one is proposing to prove by "general nonsense"?

Comment: @BCnrd: In the statement of the general proposition, there is no sheafification functor.  The result holds for any locally presentable category $C$ and any class of maps $W\subseteq Arr(C)$ satisfying the axioms.  Does that address the objection?  If not, there is also characterization of $W_\tau$ that does not depend on looking at the sheafification functor at all.  

Comment: I guess I can state it explicitly: Let $f:A\to h_X$ be a morphism in $Psh(C)$ with $h_X$ representable.  We define a sieve $S_f$ by the formula $S_f(V)=\{\rho:V\to U\in Arr(C): h_\rho:h_V\to h_U \text{ factors as }h_V\to A \overset{f}{\to} h_X\}$.  Then we say that $f$ is locally epic provided that $S_f$ is a $\tau$-covering sieve.  Given an arbitrary morphism $g:A\to B\in Psh$, we say more generally that $g$ is locally $\tau$-epic if for any map $h_V\to B$, the map $A\times_B h_V\to h_V$ is locally epic in the sense above.  

Comment: Let $E_\tau\subseteq Arr(Psh)$ denote the subclass of locally epic morphisms.  Then $W^\circ_\tau \subseteq E_\tau$ is defined to be the subclass of locally $\tau$-epic morphisms $A\to B\in Psh(C)$ such that the relative diagonal $A\to A\times_B A$ is itself locally $\tau$-epic.  We call such morphisms _local $\tau$-isomorphisms_ (this is the characterization from SGA4 that I alluded to earlier).  It is clear that these guys are a "system of local isomorphisms" and that $W^\circ_\tau\subseteq W_\tau$.  

Comment: To show the other inclusion, it suffices to show that $W^\circ_\tau$ admits a calculus of fractions (this is clear from the fact that it is stable with respect to pullbacks by arbitrary morphisms).  This together with containment of isomorphisms and 2-of-3 implies that $W^\circ_\tau$ is saturated.  Then it suffices to show that $W^\circ_\tau$ and $W_\tau$ have the same localization, but this is pretty much true by construction.  This shows that $W^\circ_\tau=W_\tau$.  With this, it is finally enough to prove that general fact.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a fairly polemical answer, in a similar spirit to Brian's:

Sheafification is not a painful process: you take a presheaf, and you think about how you need to change it so that the stalks are the same, but sections can be glued.  It is very natural.

The inverse image is also naturally understood in the same kind of terms: you have a sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$, and you would like to make a sheaf on $Y$ whose stalk at $y$ is equal
to the stalk of $\mathcal F$ at $f(y)$ (i.e. $(f^{-1}\mathcal F)_x = \mathcal F\_{f(x)}$).
If you ponder how you can make a rigorous construction with these properties, you will be led
to the inverse image.  (It's essentially taking the fibre product of $\mathcal F$ over $X$
with the map $f:Y \to X$, and indeed thinking about the inverse image is good practice for developing intuitions about fibre products in lots of other contexts.)

Using the crutch of affines and quasi-coherent sheaves *discourages* thinking about the (fairly simple and natural) local picture of a sheaf as a bunch of stalks glued together.
A lot of the power of the geometric ideas in algebraic geometry comes from thinking *geometrically*, so one doesnt' want to be discouraging thinking about sheaves in this way;
rather, you want to *encourage* it.

As for applications, Donu notes some in his answer.

Let me note another here: if $\mathcal I$ is an ideal sheaf on $X$, then $f^{-1}\mathcal I$
is naturally a subsheaf of $f^{-1} \mathcal O_X$ (because $f^{-1}$ is exact, as one sees immediately by looking on stalks and using the fact that $f^{-1}$ doesn't change stalks!), and one often wants to look at the ideal sheaf
in $\mathcal O_Y$ generated by this.  This is *not* the same (typically) as $f^*\mathcal O_Y$.  (Just as, if $I$ is an ideal in $A$ and $B$ is an $A$-algebra, $B\otimes_A I$ is typically is not isomorphic to the ideal in $B$ generated by $I$.)

Now there are other ways to describe this ideal sheaf in $\mathcal O_Y$ (e.g. it is the image
of the natural map $f^*\mathcal I \to \mathcal O_Y$), but the description of it in terms
of $f^{-1}\mathcal I$ is convenient and very natural.

Comment: Dear Emerton, certainly you have made a good case for thinking of sheaves on spaces as a bunch of stalks glued together, but unless I'm quite mistaken, doesn't this picture fail to generalize to sheaves on more general sites? 

Comment: If the site doesn't have enough points, then perhaps so.  But it's a bit like the Grothendieck "functor of points" view-point:  eventually we can think of any morphism as being a "point" of its source, but in the beginning, its good to understand geometric objects as being collections of points (in the more conventional sense) sweeping out some shape.  This lets when one develop some geometric intuition (which is, after all, the point of the "functor of points" metaphor: one wants to use it as a tool through which geometric intuition can be channelled) before moving onto more abstract things. 

Comment: Returning more directly to your comment: in the etale site one has enough points, and so the picture I'm emphasizing continues to make sense.  (And this is one of the things that makes the etale site so pleasant.)  On the other hand, if one wants to work in the crystalline site/topos (just to give an example where a more topos-theoretic viewpoint is needed), one has to deal with constructions that are much more involved than forming $f^{-1}$, and so the advice that one should learn this first (and not skip over it) still seems to be pretty reasonable.

Comment: Dear Emerton, you don't mean that $f^{-1}$ is not useful in the crystalline site/topos though, right?  The functor $f^{-1}$ is the "more important half" of the adjunction defining a geometric morphism (induced by a morphism of underlying sites).  

Comment: Dear Harry, No, I don't mean that.  What I have in mind, rather, is that the crystalline site/topos is one of the first contexts in which topos-theoretic issues really matter.  E.g. the morphism of crystalline topoi induced by a morphism $f:X \to Y$ does not arise from a corresponding morphism of sites (unlike in the etale case), and, when computing crystalline cohomology, there is no final object in the crystalline site (again, unlike in the Zariski or etale case), and so to compute the cohomology, one really has to use the final object in the topos.  

Comment: ... So, when constructing morphisms of crystalline topoi, or computing crystalline cohomology, one is *forced* to make sheaf-theoretic constructions all over the place (because you have to work with the topoi, not just the sites).  Practicing thinking about $f^{-1}$ (in the comparatively simple case of a map of topological spaces) is one way to build up the sheaf-theoretic intuition necessary for understanding what is going on in more complicated contexts such as the crystalline one.

Answer (score 17):

One quick answer is that the stalk of a sheaf $F$ at a point (say, given by an inclusion $f\colon pt \to X$) is just $f^{-1}F$.

Answer (score 10):

Donu Arapura (and BCnrd) already made this point, but I want to emphasize it: algebraic geometry employs a whole universe of sheaves that do not have $\mathscr{O}_X$ actions, and in those cases, the inverse image is the pullback of choice.  Standard examples include:

1. Sheaves of solutions to a system of linear algebraic differential equations, in other words, flat sections of a quasicoherent sheaf with respect to a connection.  Sometimes these are reasonably familiar, e.g., when they are locally constant.
2. $\ell$-adic sheaves on (the étale site of) a variety over a finite field of characteristic $p$ - this was the first toolset for proving the Weil conjectures.
3. Sheaves of sets, for studying representability and so on.
4. Sheaves of commutative monoids, in log geometry.
5. Sheaves of closed differential forms (which appear when studying e.g., characteristic classes related to twisted differential operators)

I've definitely seen the inverse image employed in the first 4 cases, and I wouldn't be surprised if it appeared in the fifth.

Comment: I would also add : 6. Sheaves of groups (such as the multiplicative group whose first cohomology group is the Picard group).

Comment: ACL, that is a very nice example.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer the definition of $f^\*$ as a left-adjoint to $f_* : Mod(X) \to Mod(Y)$. The formula involving inverse image is then basically abstract nonsense using a transitivity argument with constant sheaves, at least philosophical. The proof of existence is another issue, but it follows from rather general facts of category theory (Kan extensions).

Anyway, your question was about the use of $f^{-1}$ in algebraic geometry. An example is the reduced structure sheaf on a closed subset of a locally ringed space. You take the vanishing ideal $I$ and then pull back $\mathcal{O}_X / I$ along the inclusion map, which is a priori just a continuous map. You can also view this as a module pull back, but only if you have already defined the structure sheaf.

Also, I think it is very important to learn the somewhat old-fashioned view on sheaves, namely as sections of the etale space. Then you quickly arrive at the question to which sheaf corresponds to restriction of the etale space to a subset, which is not necessarily open. Well, it is just the pullback with respect to the inclusion map.

Finally, it is good to know that the morphism $f^{\#} : \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*} \mathcal{O}_X$, appearing in the definiton of a morphism of a ringed spaces, corresponds to a morphism $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_X$, from which you get the stalk maps directly.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, an element of $\varinjlim_{V\supseteq f(U)} \Gamma(V, \mathcal{F})$ is just a section in an open neighborhood of $f(U)$ (with some proper identifications).

On the other hand, a section $s\in \Gamma(U, f^{-1}\mathcal{F})$ is 
given by an open cover $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $f(U)$ and a section $s_i\in \Gamma(V_i, \mathcal{F})$ for each $i\in I$ for which we require that 
$$ s_i\mid_{V_i\cap V_j \cap f(U)} = s_j\mid_{V_i\cap V_j \cap f(U)}.$$
Here equality means stalk-wise equality. In other words, $s_i=s_j \in \mathcal{F}_y$ for every $y\in V_i\cap V_j \cap f(U)$.  Given two such collections $\{(s_i, V_i)\}$ and $\{(t_j, W_j)\}$, we say they are equal if they match stalk-wise for every point $y\in f(U)$.

The difference is just that one substitute a "global" statement where a section in $\Gamma(U,f^{-1}\mathcal{F})$ is required to extend to a nbhd of the whole of $f(U)$ for a "local" version of essentially the same statement and require the sections to glue together on $f(U)$.

For example, if we have $V_1\cup V_2 \supseteq f(U)$ and sections $s_i$ over the respective open sets. We might have $s_1$ and $s_2$ matches on $f(U)\cap V_1\cap V_2$ but differs at some point $y\not\in f(U)$, so they fail to glue to a section on $V_1\cup V_2$. 
The good thing here is that in this case the support of $s_1-s_2$ is closed in $V_1\cap V_2$, after shrinking our open sets $V_1$ and $V_2$, the sections do match on the intersection.  Of course you expect this method to fail when infinite open sets are involved.  This also leads to the idea that once compactness is involved, then one may have hope for this to work.  For example, see Lemma 1 of [Akhil Mathew's Note](http://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/soft-sheaves/).